# Partition compression of a tree and how to compress nodes to root

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, dictionary

[image]

I'm trying to compress all the ancestors of a given node by having them point to the root of the parameter node passed to

```
 private E compressToRoot (E e) throws IllegalArgumentException;
```

For example, in the image above, if I did compressToRoot(D) then D would point directly to A and C would point directly to A. If there were other nodes between the parameter and the root then they would all point to A.

All of the labels and arrows are stored in two separate maps:

```
private Map<E,E>       parentMap   = new HashMap<E,E>(); //labels + arrows
```

I can complete this method by (1) holding all the nodes between D and the root in a set. (2) having all elements of the set point to (make parent) the root (3) return the root.

However, I'm stuck on how I can traverse this map to get to the root. So, for the method I would do something along the lines of

```
private E compressToRoot (E e) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Set<E> collectLables = new HashSet<E>();
E root = null;

//get root.
for (E cycle : parentMap.keys()) {
    while (parentMap.get(e) != e) 
        e = parentMap.get(e);
        if (parentMap.get(e) == e)
            root = cycle;
 }


//collect all labels from parameter to root.
for (E element : parentMap.keys()) {
    while (parentMap.get(e) != root) {
        collectLables.add(element);
    }   
}


}
```

But I'm not sure how I can cycle through the parents of the given node all the way to the root.

Comment: Why does E point to A in your image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive is pretty, but favor an iterative method if the length of a longest  path to the root may get large. You don't want to run out of stack.

```
private E compressToRoot(E node) {
    if (parentMap.get(node) != node)
        parentMap.set(node, compressToRoot(node));
    return parentMap.get(node);
}

private E compressToRoot(E cursor) {
    E node;
    ArrayList<E> nodes = new ArrayList<E>();
    while ((node = parentMap.get(cursor)) != cursor)  {
        nodes.add(cursor);
        cursor = node;
    }

    for (node : nodes)
        parentMap.set(node, cursor);

    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm stuck on how I can traverse this map to get to the root.

It appears that your definition of the "root" is the only node which points to itself. It's not particularly efficient, but you could just look for a such element:

```
E findRoot(Map<E, E> parentMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<E, E> entry: parentMap.entrySet() {
        if (entry.key().equals(entry.value()) {
            return entry;
        }
    }

    // parentMap is empty, or the graph is corrupted
    // handle this edge case however you want
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to clarify the design if I've failed to understand.

Comment: The return type is Map.Entry<E,E>. So, how would I make sure only the parents of the parameter node pointed to this entry? (And not some other nodes such as B in the picture above?

Comment: I don't know. What you have looks more like a general-purpose graph representation than a tree, specifically, which does not immediately make a ton of sense to me. If you're going to store a tree like that then you'll need to write code to ensure the invariants are true. Is there a specific reason you use a map to represent edges rather than the more-typical `Node` which just stores references to its children (optionally with a parent reference as well)?

Comment: No specific reason. But since this is a graph, each key would have a value that is the next ancestor. So to go from D -> root I would simply set the value from D (value = c) to point to the root from findRoot right?

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but like I said I don't entirely understand your design. Give it a shot, see how far you get with it.

Answer (score 1):

A slight potential improvement to [rambo coder's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13656629/337475), depending on the efficiency of the Map. You can do it without using the extra memory and overhead for the `ArrayList` by just traversing the path twice:

```
private E compressToRoot(E cursor) {
    E cursor2 = cursor;
    E node = parentMap.get(cursor);
    while (node != cursor)  {
        cursor = node;
        node = parentMap.get(node);
    }
    // Now cursor (and node) are the root.    

    node = parentMap.get(cursor2);
    while (node != cursor2) {
        parentMap.set(cursor2, cursor);
        cursor2 = node;
        node = parentMap.get(node);
    }

    return cursor;
}
```